# How can I mock bean returning its own parameter?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I have a repository class something like ...

```
public class StuffRepository {
    public Stuff save(Stuff v);
}
```

I want to make a mock with @MockBean returning first parameter v.
How can I do that?

```
@MockBean
private StuffRepository stuffRepository;

public void test() {
    given(stuffRepository.save(??)).willReturn(??);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `Answer` mocking version.

```
given(stuffRepository.save(any())).will(i -> {
    return i.getArgument(0);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Mock up`Stuff` and have that be the return value.

```
@MockBean
private StuffRepository stuffRepository;
@Mock
private Stuff v;

public void test() {
    given(stuffRepository.save(v)).willReturn(v);
}
```